# Cannot read property '__useDefault' of undefined

Tags: aurelia, jspm

I have a project that is using `jspm-git` to download code into the `\jspm_packages` folder.

Even though everything has downloaded fine, I am getting the following error:

```
aurelia-loader-default.js:55 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '__useDefault' of undefined
    at ensureOriginOnExports (aurelia-loader-default.js:55)
    at eval (aurelia-loader-default.js:247)
    at <anonymous>
```

Any ideas how I can fix this, or debug this, etc ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some details? The module object that the aurelia loader receives should not be undefined. What are you importing? What is your configuration?

Answer (score 1):

For NPM scoped packages make sure you properly include the dependency on aurelia.json, as they indicate here: 
https://aurelia.io/docs/build-systems/aurelia-cli#adding-client-libraries-to-your-project

```
 "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "@scope/packagename",
      "path": "../node_modules/@scope/packagename/dist/amd",
      "main": "packagename"
    }
  ]
```

For example, for adding the aurelia-kendoui-bridge you would add this:

```
{
  "name": "aurelia-kendoui-bridge",
  "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-kendoui-bridge/dist/amd",
  "main": "index"
}
```

Most of the time the developer of the library will provide documentation for configuring the dependencies on Aurelia.